# Stack trace is not printed in proper order with other messages on console

Tags: java, eclipse, console, stack-trace

**Why** does it happen that the *stack trace* printed for the following Java program is not displayed in a proper order on the console screen? It gets mixed up with other messages on the screen.

Is there any parallelism involved which causes it?

**Java program:**

```
package evm;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EVM evm = new EVM();
        
        try {
            evm.setCandidates(90);   /**An Exception thrown here**/
        } catch (CandidatesOutOfLimitsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        try {
            evm.voteForCandidate(43);    /**An Exception thrown here**/
        } catch (BallotUnitOffException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.print(e1.getMessage());
        }

        evm.pressBallotButton();
        
        System.out.println(evm);  //other messages
        evm.switchOn();
        System.out.println(evm);  //other messages
        
        try {
            evm.voteForCandidate(43);    /**An Exception thrown here**/
        } catch (BallotUnitOffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I have commented against the lines which throw an Exception.

**run 1:**

```
evm.CandidatesOutOfLimitsException: Number of Candidates cannot exceed 64
    at evm.EVM.setCandidates(EVM.java:41)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:9)
evm.BallotUnitOffException: Ballot Unit is not On
    at evm.BallotUnit.pressCandidateButton(BallotUnit.java:38)
    at evm.EVM.voteForCandidate(EVM.java:59)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:16)
evm.BallotUnitOffException: Ballot Unit is not On
    at evm.BallotUnit.pressCandidateButton(BallotUnit.java:38)
    at evm.EVM.voteForCandidate(EVM.java:59)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:28)

Control Unit State: evm.Off@42a57993
On Lamp: evm.Off@15db9742Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@6d06d69c
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchOne@7852e922
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@4e25154f
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchTwo@70dea4e
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@5c647e05
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchThree@33909752
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@55f96302
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchFour@3d4eac69


Control Unit State: evm.On@28d93b30
On Lamp: evm.On@75b84c92Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@6bc7c054
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchOne@7852e922
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@232204a1
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchTwo@70dea4e
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@4aa298b7
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchThree@33909752
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@7d4991ad
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchFour@3d4eac69
```

**run 2:**

```
evm.CandidatesOutOfLimitsException: Number of Candidates cannot exceed 64
    at evm.EVM.setCandidates(EVM.java:41)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:9)
evm.BallotUnitOffException: Ballot Unit is not On
    at evm.BallotUnit.pressCandidateButton(BallotUnit.java:38)
    at evm.EVM.voteForCandidate(EVM.java:59)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:16)

Control Unit State: evm.Off@42a57993
On Lamp: evm.Off@15db9742Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@6d06d69c
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchOne@7852e922
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@4e25154f
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchTwo@70dea4e
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@5c647e05
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchThree@33909752
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.Off@55f96302
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchFour@3d4eac69


Control Unit State: evm.On@28d93b30
On Lamp: evm.On@75b84c92Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@6bc7c054
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchOne@7852e922
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@232204a1
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchTwo@70dea4e
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@4aa298b7
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchThree@33909752
Ballot Unit: Ready Lamp: evm.On@7d4991ad
Slide Switch:evm.SlideSwitchFour@3d4eac69

evm.BallotUnitOffException: Ballot Unit is not On
    at evm.BallotUnit.pressCandidateButton(BallotUnit.java:38)
    at evm.EVM.voteForCandidate(EVM.java:59)
    at evm.Client.main(Client.java:28)
```

Similarly I get some other patterns every time I run it. Anybody explain this behavior.

I am using

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
>
> Build id: 20140612-0600

*I apologize for lengthy question*

Comment: `println()` is threadsafe but combination of `printStackTrace()` and `println()` could cause results like this because one method writes to the standard error stream while the other writes to the standard output stream. The O/p though logged seperately can be interleaved and displayed on your console

Comment: @TheLostMind that should be an answer

Comment: @fge - I was afraid  that the information provided was less :)

Comment: @TheLostMind  but is it a problem only with combination of `printStackTrace()` and `println()` or are there other combinations? any solution for it if i need to see the messages in order? put it as an answer if any solution for it

Comment: @Shri - There could be other combinations as well... One solution is to write to only one stream (not suggested).

Comment: @TheLostMind how can i write to only one stream?

Comment: e.printStackTrace(System.out)

Comment: @schtever ya got it. so `e.printStackTrace(System.out)` will print it instead on the _output stream_ right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  By default, `e.printStacktrace` prints to System.err.

Comment: Hey everybody, comments are for clarifying questions and such. Answers belong in the answer section. How about posting an answer, somebody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do more with the implementation of the standard output and error streams than Eclipse.

Both `System.out` and `System.err` are [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.File)) objects which may be passed buffered streams that do not automatically flush data to their destinations. Since they are two different streams with buffering used internally, the data you write to them may be interleaved because the streams may decide to flush at different times (the buffer contents may be filled at different times).

Calling `System.err.flush()` after printing the first two stack traces and then `System.out.flush()` after printing to the std output stream should get consistent results.

Comment: another way of doing it is suggested by schtever in the comment on question. what is your opinion about it? which one is better?

Comment: @Shri It would work but it is not conventional to print error stack traces to std out and seems more like a workaround.

Comment: i understand this is getting annoying but can you tell me why its so?

Comment: If you look at the Javadoc of [`System.err`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err), it mentions: _"By convention, this output stream is used to display error messages or other information that should come to the immediate attention of a user..."_. Printing the exception to the standard output does not follow this convention. On an unrelated note, have you tried to use a logging library instead of using `System.out` and `System.err`? If yes, does it have the same problem.

Comment: No I only tried with `printStackTrace()`. Well I got the answer but wanted a good explanation so that it might benefit anyone who comes across this. You did it well..